# Como criar um tuplo que armazena os detalhes da informação gerada(encomenda)?

Tags: python, lista, tupla

```
    have_discount = []

    no_discount = []

    for each_price in purchases_prices:
        b = bool_gen(p)
        if b:
            have_discount.append(apply_discount(each_price,b))
            have_discount = [round(each_price, 2) for each_price in have_discount]
        else:    
            no_discount.append(apply_discount(each_price,b))        

    #games_tags
    games_tags = []
    for code_game, game_name in stock.items():
        if code_game in codes_being_purchased:
            games_tags.append(game_name)

    #cost of all itens
    total_cost = round(sum(have_discount) + sum(no_discount),2)

    #total discount 
    total_discount = round(sum(purchases_prices) - total_cost,2)

    print('Dear customer', customer_id,',' , 'your order_id is',order_id,'and it contains',len(games_tags),'itens, which makes a total cost of', round(total_cost,2), 'and a discount was applied to', len(have_discount),'itens.') 
    print('Thanks for choosing us!')
 O que retorna da função é:
 Dear customer 8890 , your order_id is 26287 and it contains 6 itens, which makes a total cost of 256.2 and a discount was applied to 4 itens
 Dear customer 8655 , your order_id is 5259 and it contains 6 itens, which makes a total cost of 247.77 and a discount was applied to 7 itens.

 Dear customer 8400 , your order_id is 48297 and it contains 3 itens, which makes a total cost of 72.47 and a discount was applied to 1 itens.
```

Eu gostaria de armazenar todas as informações de cada encomenda da seguinte maneira(e com base no exemplo):

tuple = ((8890,26287,6,256.2,4),(8655,529,6,247.77,7),...)

Update:

```
    list_discount = []
    list_customer_id = []
    list_order_id = []
    list_games_tags = []
    list_total_cost = []
    for info in range(customers):
        list_customer_id.append(customer_id)
        list_order_id.append(order_id)
        list_games_tags.append(len(games_tags))
        list_total_cost.append(total_cost)
        list_discount.append(len(have_discount))
    order_tuple =(list_customer_id,list_order_id,list_games_tags,list_total_cost,list_discount)
        return order_tuple
```

customerSim(10)

Output dos append:

```
([429, 429, 429, 429, 429, 429, 429, 429, 429, 429],
 [25835, 25835, 25835, 25835, 25835, 25835, 25835, 25835, 25835, 25835],
 [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
 [280.42,
 280.42,
 280.42,
 280.42,
 280.42,
 280.42,
 280.42,
 280.42,
 280.42,
 280.42],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Comment: queria criar um tuplo que armazenasse todos os detalhes da encomenda... da forma como está descrita na figura acima...eu criei uma função que gera aleatoriamente as encomendas! e queria armazenar num tuplo a info gerada de cada uma

Comment: Ué, aparentemente você já fez tudo.. Não seria só criar as tuplas com o valor que você quer? Tipo `(customer_id, order_id, len(game_tags), round(total_cost, 2), len(have_discount))`??

Comment: sim mas não estou a conseguir iterar cada valor de cada cliente...

Comment: é só criar uma lista vazia e dar um `append` depois que cada um dos valores foi calculado. Se você pesquisar aqui no site deve achar muitos exemplos para estudar...

Comment: eu já fiz isso mas não deu...vou dar edit e meter o que ja fiz em relação ao append! Já está!

Comment: só armazena a info do último cliente... e eu queria de todos(do primeiro ao ultimo)

Comment: Teu código ta estranho, só ta sendo mantido um valor em todo array porque você ta usando a mesma variável sempre. Você tem o `info` gerado a partir de um `range`, mas em nenhum momento você usa isso. No `list_customer_id` você ta dando `append` na mesma variável `customer_id` sem atualizar ela.

Comment: imagino que no caso da primeira linha deveria ser algo como:
`for info in range(len(customers)): list_customer_id.append(customers[info][customer_id])`

Comment: Não que seja isso, mas acho que da pra ter uma ideia.

Comment: Confesso que não entendi o problema. Sendo assim retorno com uma pergunta: tem certeza que a vc quer usar tuple como estrutura de dados? Acredito que uma lista de objetos, ou uma lista de `namedtuples` (`from collections import namedtuple`), ou uma lista de dicionários, seria bem mais adequado